# Simplify 'Save As CSV' Procedure

Tags: excel

When I try to save the .csv file in Excel I get prompted to three additional windows asking me to save something. I don't bother to read but it's getting tiring to click `No` or `Cancel` each time:

[image: SaveAs CSV confirmation]
How do I set Excel to just save my file when I press CTRL+S?

Comment: I edited the code and made screen shot.

Comment: I edited the "comment" and pasted screen shot.

Comment: You can write a macro specifically for csv files and assign it a shortcut key. Save that macro in the personal.xlsb?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> habitually, then it is probably unwise to rewrite that keystroke combination. However, there is nothing to stop you from expanding its usefulness by assigning a new Save-As-CSV to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

The best place to put the following will depend somewhat on your individual situation, of which little has been provided. Using a **Personal.xlsb** has been suggested; embedding into a macro-enabled template is another and of course, you can simply put them into a module code sheet within the workbook you are currently processing.

```
Sub no_training_wheels(Optional ws As Worksheet)
    Dim fn As String
    If IsEmpty(ws) Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        .Activate
        If CBool(Application.CountA(.Cells)) Then
            If CBool(Len(.Parent.Path)) Then
                fn = .Parent.Path & Chr(92) & Left(.Parent.Name & Chr(46), InStr(1, .Parent.Name, Chr(46)) - 1)
            Else
                fn = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
                    InitialFileName:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & Chr(92) & ActiveSheet.Name, _
                    fileFilter:="Comma Separated Value files (*.csv), *.csv")
                If LCase(fn) = "false" Then fn = Environ("TEMP") & Chr(92) & .Name
            End If
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .Parent.SaveAs Filename:=fn, FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub take_training_wheels_off()
    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="no_training_wheels", ShortcutKey:="S", _
                             Description:="Alternate Save-to-CSV without warnings"
End Sub

Sub put_training_wheels_on()
    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="no_training_wheels", ShortcutKey:="", _
                             Description:="Alternate Save-to-CSV without warnings"
End Sub
```

The macro has an optional worksheet parameter to expand its use to other coded routines. This also has the effect of removing from the Macro Name: list in the Macro Run dialog. There are two 'helper' routines to enable and disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> keystroke combination. A regular save operation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> is unaffected.

I have inferred from you wish to avoid dialogs and most interaction from the narrative *'I don't bother to read but it's getting tiring to click No or Cancel each time'* and that you happily accept the defaults and simply wish to Save-to-CSV with as little interaction as possible. To that end, I have made some assumptions. You might want to review them before using the routine *carte blanche*.

[Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx)